# Qt Shouldn't the method logicalDpiX() return different values for screens of the same resolution but different size?

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt Creator 4.10 based on Qt 5.13.1 (build Sep 4 2019).

I'm trying to find the DPIs of a screen.
I have 2 screens. One the Laptop which has a resolution of 1920 by 1080 and a monitor of 22 inches with the same resolution of 1920 by 1080.

```
DPIfactor = ui->Time->logicalDpiX();
```

Time is a QLabel.

Regardless of which screen I run Qt Creator and the Application, DPIfactor is always set to 144.
Shouldn't the smaller screen (the main screen of the laptop) have a higher DPI value?
Since they have both the same resolution the one of smaller size should have higher Dots Per Inch...

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: What does [`physicalDpiX`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html#physicalDpiX) report for the two screens?

Comment: The same value of 144! That is the problem as I see it...

Comment: Which device do you use? Please look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#devicePixelRatio 
Maybe they have a different devicePixelRatio

Comment: I get  
devicePixelRatio()      :  1 
devicePixelRatioF()     :  1 
devicePixelRatioFScale():  65536

on both screens...